# gdb showing incorrect double value

Tags: c++

I had a strange behavior with my program in which the double was losing the precision. My cout's were showing correct values but still the behavior was unexpected. Hence i debugged and found even gdb shows unexpected values. 
Following is only the simplified scenario:

```
double length =2.11;
//gdb shows 2.10 here but prints 2.11 correctly using cout at the end
cout<<"length; //It prints 2.11 correctly here
```

Often such issues are hard to find on production scenarios where debugging is not an option and the only option is using as many prints as possible.
Any suggestions how can i avoid this problem?

Comment: Wrong question (because you forgot to motivate it, and actually have some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)...). As you commented, you don't manipulate *numbers* but some baroque length representation (since you commented that `2.11` would mean 2 feet and 11 inches)

Comment: If you use `double` be sure to take several hours to read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Absolutely good advice. Armed with this knowledge, you also go down a hoot at parties.

Comment: So your title is wrong. `gdb` is showing some nearly correct value. In general, question first your code before suspecting your tools.

Comment: I downvoted the question, because it is really so different of your actual problem (making the mistake of using a `double` for something which is not even a number)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming IEEE754 double precision floating point, the closest `double` to 2.11 is the slightly smaller

`2.109999999999999875655021241982467472553253173828125`

`std::cout` is clever enough to round appropriately by default, but gdb appears to be truncating to 2 decimal places.

Comment: How do i avoid this? Assuming i have a double variable as `double var=2.11` where 2 represents feets and 11 the inches, how can i extract 0.11 part fromn here since it always makes it 10 instead of 11

Comment: That's a questionable use of a `double`, and not trivial to solve. Why not use a `struct` modelling the `feet` and `inches` separately? You could even build a "normalise" method on it which converts things like 1 foot 13 inches to 2 feet 1 inch.

Comment: Having such a representation is a huge mistake. `double` are *approximating* [real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number). Your data is not even a number. Either (and preferably) *convert* it to some length (e.g. in *meters*), or keep something else (a `std::string`, a `std::pair<float,float>`)

Comment: The user is entering 2.11, so even if i were to use struct i would be required to finally extract it. So finally the way i should input the number from the user is incorrect here. I should input 2 first and then 11 instead of 2.11. Is that correct or you have something else to convey n context of using structs?

Comment: Your `struct` contains a *constructor* to a `std::string`. Job done. You could even build the appropriate overload to `>>` so you can use it with `cin`. Ain't C++ great?!

Comment: Yes, have your user enter some `std::string` (e.g. the `2.11` input would become `std::string("2.11")` value)  then use usual [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques to validate and interpret it.

Answer (score 2):

Given the fact that real numbers behave as they did in your case, I fear there isn't much to do about it. You could have planned for it to avoid it, and  created space to perform equality checks over your double values.

Here are two plausible hacks for you:

1: [Tried this in a college project] To deal with numbers in the order 10^-4, use an integer and a factor value. Example: to store 1.2345, store like integer 12345 and factor as 10000. Now you can print correctly and this also give feasibility to do equality checks also.

2: If accuracy of double values is already known you can use an offset. Example: if 2.109999 has accuracy of 2 decimal places, use something like this:
(int)((2.109999 + .005)*100). And then print accordingly.

But both these hacks assume following:

1: You have control on accuracy of values.
2: you really need printing accurate values.